# Multiple application android:name tags in application tag in Android manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

Multiple application android:name tags in manifest

My two java class extended by application and I am confused. How can I define two android name tags in application tag in Android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

the statements.json that you are referring to is for app links

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/app-linking.html

which is a totally different purpose. This is so that your app can be the default handler for certain URL pattern scheme without user picking from the list of app that declare matching scheme.

For example: if user click on a link to http://myapp.com/page123

And they have two apps declare for URL scheme myapp.com. Normally, user will get a pop up asking them which app should handle this link. However your app is signed with matching key from myapp.com statements.json then your app will be launched to handle the link over the other guy.